# Grafana loki Logstash client - Grafana not picking labels

Tags: logstash, grafana-loki

Im trying to connect the grafana loki with log stash client. Grafana is able to detect the datasource but labels are not detecting.
Instead of loki config **stdout { codec => rubydebug}** the logs are printing in the console.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: log-stash-configmap
  namespace: loki-benchmark
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
      input {
      file {
        path => "/var/log/*.*"
        type => "var log"
        start_position => "beginning"
      }
      }
      filter {}
      output {
        loki {
          url => "http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki-benchmark.svc.cluster.local:3100"
        }
      }
```

[image]